# Share active directory session Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, active-directory, single-sign-on

We have several **webapps** based in Wordpress and Codeigniter, which are based on different servers but under the same domain (ie: intranet.something.local) and most of them use Active Directory login credentials.

For **Wordpress**, I'm using a plugin called **Active Directory Integration** to log in with these credentials and it's working perfectly after configuring openLDAP.

The thing is, our client asked us to have a single log on for every app, meaning that once I'm logged into Wordpress, I should be logged in when I go to another app, that uses the same login user and password.

Is there a possible way to do this? And if so, where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that is possible in multiple ways..

1. Setup [Single Sign On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) in your apps
2. Use a script which automatically copies User data from a web app,
       and then using that information creates user login to the other
       apps..Idea is to let user register for one site, and based on that information, register him to other sites automatically
3. May be, some sort of Database sharing be possible, but that would be
       really really a tough job, still Possible (I believe, in Computer
       Science, nothing is impossible forever)
4. create a common cookie file and when user switches the app, use that
   cookies to get the user login in between different apps